# Autocomplete RichTextBox in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, autocomplete, richtextbox, text-editor

I am making a text editor and I want to make a autocomplete for the RichTextBox which the text is inside her, but I have no clue how to do this. I checked the internet and all of it is how to do it with a normal TextBox...

I would really appreciate to get help with that if someone knows how to do it.

Comment: Ignoring the text editor, how would the autocomplete work? How would the computer know how to autocomplete the word?

Comment: It just shows a box with all possible words that starts with what the user wrote.

Comment: How do you find all possible words?

Comment: From a list that includes them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your custom auto-complete I would recommend you use the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) but only calculate the distance of items that already start or contain the already typed-in text that you want to autocomplete.

Other then that I do recommend you [check this out](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/1782/how-to-implement-autocomplete-with-richtextbox-control), it should work as you want it but it might not appear in the toolbox, as I have not tried that myself.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the first and second link means... I do understand that in the second link it basically changes the richTextBox class(fix me if I am wrong)... But I have no idea how to do that, (reminder: I am pretty new to .NET).

Comment: @TalMoshel Sorry for the extremely late response, I am not really that active on SO.   The first link is basically an algorithm to determine how much do you need to edit a word to match a second. Ex: ant and plants. You need 3 edits because you need to add pl and s at the end. Of course, if you do not want it to correct the first part of the word, store a temporary list of all words that start with "ant" from the overall list of potential auto-corrects you provide it.

The second link is making a **new** richTextBox class but it makes it so you can add the auto-complete things from TextBox.